# Arquitectura "amd64" y "armvf"

Tags: linux, unix, raspberry-pi, electron

Tengo una serie de dudas sobre la arquitectura de "amd64" y "armvf". Todo esto surge porque me compre una Raspberry Pi 3 B+ para poder usarla con Ubuntu Core y Snap, para correr mir-kiosk y poder por ejemplo tener la aplicación de Spotify en un sistema embebido para conectarla a un sistema de audio. Estaba feliz porque creía que iba a funcionar hasta que al intentar instalar la App me dice que solo está disponible para sistemas con arquitectura de amd64 y la Raspberry Pi cuenta con "armv7l" para 32Bits, por lo tanto no la pude instalar.

Bueno el tema es que el 99% de todas las Apps en Snapcraft están compiladas solo para arquitecturas "amd64" que tengo entendido que funciona para cualquier procesador Intel o AMD de 64 bits y no para ARM así sea de 64 bits, aunque la Raspberry Pi 3 B+ en Ubuntu Core se instala como de 32 bits. El caso es que por ejemplo, si queremos usar una Raspberry Pi también con una impresora que solo cuenta con los drivers para "amd64" no va funcionar, ahora me queda en la cabeza el fastidio de todo esto, porque el equipo de Raspberry PI no utiliza un sistema compatible con amd64. Pues nada alguien que me ilumine un poco mi cerebro.

Comment: ¿ Que te ilumine en qué ? ¿ Cual es la pregunta ? Si ya te lo has dicho tu solito todo, las aplicaciones se ejecutan en la arquitectura para la que se compilan, a menos que sean interpretadas (python, por ejemplo)

Comment: @Trauma Gracias por responder, la pregunta es el motivo por el cual se utiliza más la arquitectura "amd64" en lugar de compilar para todas las arquitecturas, cual es la desventaja o la parte oculta.

Comment: Esta pregunta acabará cerrada por *basada en opiniones* o por *demasiado amplia*. Lo que estás preguntando es, mas o menos, porqué algunos programas solo están para Windows y no para Linux (salvando las diferencias). Hay **múltiples** motivos, incluido el simple hecho de que al desarrollador no le apetezca. Las diferencias entre una y otra arquitectura pueden ser lo bastante amplias como para que el proceso de desarrollo sea prácticamente doble. ¿ Merece la pena dedicar tantos recursos para algo que se usará de forma marginal ? ¿ Por 5 o 10 usuarios ?

Comment: @Trauma, Vamos que la pregunta no está tan abierta. Actualmente estoy aprendiendo electronjs, en el caso de Spotify, Skype, VSCode, están hechas en con electronjs. Si podemos compilar para varias arquitecturas con por ejemplo: electron-builder, electron-forge, con una simple configuración porque no hacerlo?.. Hablo de Linux en específico, creo que existen más motivos que los motiva a no hacerlo. Tan simple como haber compilado a Spotify que está hecho en electronjs para todas las arquitecturas y poder usarlo en iot que es a lo que le apunta Ubuntu Core.

Comment: Tal y como la has formulado, está **muy muy abierta**. Si hubieras preguntado lo que has puesto en tu último comentario, la cosa cambiaría.

Comment: ¿ Está Electron portado para `arm` ? ¿ La aplicación que te interesa usa algún tipo de código **nativo** aparte del propio Electron ? ¿ Está ese código nativo portado para `arm` ?

Comment: Así es, "the armv7l binary is built against ARM v7 with hard-float ABI and NEON for Debian Wheezy." Como dije la idea de haber logrado correr Spotify en un Raspberry PI corriendo Ubuntu Core con la imagen "snap" publicada en la store de Snapcraft quedó en un fracaso por la arquitectura de Rp, la única solución que veo es comprar una placa con soporte para "amd64" o hay algo más que se pueda hacer?

Comment: ¿ Así es el que ? ¿ Que Electron está para Raspberry ? ¿ Y las otras 2 cuestiones ?

Comment: La solución mas rápida es lo que has dicho, comprar hardware que soporte el software.

Comment: O usar un software que si esté soportado por tu hardware :-)

Answer (score 1):

Veo diferentes problemáticas dentro de la misma pregunta, por lo que es, obviamente, demasiado amplia para responder de forma concisa en una misma respuesta.
Trataré de ser discreto a cada parte. Te lo escribo a ti, pero está enfocado para cualquier otro usuario.

---

Voy a ceñirme a esta parte, ahora mismo:

> Todo esto surge porque me compre una Raspberry Pi 3 B+ para poder usarla con Ubuntu Core y Snap, para correr mir-kiosk y poder por ejemplo tener la aplicación de Spotify en un sistema embebido para conectarla a un sistema de audio.

Tu pregunta es, específicamente, esta. Todo lo demás, marea a quien te intenta responder, así que me ceñiré a ella.

La aplicación *Spotify* no está compilada para "Raspberry PI". Las comillas significan que intentas asumir que "Raspberry PI" es un sistema operativo, y no lo es, es un hardware. Esto es lo primero que debo remarcarte, porque veo que confundes demasiado la terminología hard y soft, y tengo que aclarártelo, tanto para ti como para el resto de usuarios.

Tampoco Snap te asegura que estén todos los paquetes de *Ubuntu Core* para "Raspberry PI", porque están sólo los que estén dentro de *Snap*, que no son todos los que existen, como en tu caso, la aplicación *Spotify*. [Extrayendo de aquí](https://www.redeszone.net/2017/05/05/probar-snap-raspberry-pi-raspbian/):

> **Aunque la implementación aún no está del todo lista** ya se puede probar. Por ello, a continuación, os explicamos cómo activar desde ya este nuevo sistema de paquetes en el sistema operativo oficial del Raspberry Pi, Raspbian.

De hecho, en la misma web que he puesto antes aclaran para qué sistemas operativos serviría:

> Ahora le ha llegado el turno a **Raspbian**, el SO del Raspberry Pi

¿Quiere decir que es el único sistema operativo que existe para Raspberry Pi?
**No**, no lo es, pero a partir de ahora, ya no asumo que te equivoques, sino que haces el error deliberadamente para confundir al resto de usuarios de la comunidad.

---

## Arquitectura hardware

Ahora toca la parte de

> Tengo una serie de dudas sobre la arquitectura de "amd64" y "armvf".

No veo el listado de dudas, sino que lo que tienes es una confusión sobre mezclar hardware y software en el mismo contexto. Esto puede provocar confusión a la hora de que te cierren la pregunta por ser demasiado amplia.

Lo que tú llamas "arquitectura", es, literalmente, **la arquitectura del hardware** donde se podrá ejecutar la aplicación que quieres, en el sistema operativo que haya para dicha aplicación. No hay que confundirla con la arquitectura software, que es otra cosa totalmente distinta.

Hay muchísimas arquitecturas, tantas como tipos diferentes de procesadores.

Las más comunes y las que se estudian con más asiduidad son:

- X86

  1. 32 bits: [X86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)
  2. 64 bits: [X86_64 o amd64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)
- [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)

  1. 32 bits (cores cortex): ARMv8-R, ARMv8-M, ARMv7-A, ARMv7-R, ARMv7E-M, ARMv7-M, ARMv6-M
  2. 32 o 64 bits: ARMv8-A, ARMv8.1-A, ARMv8.2-A, ARMv8.3-A, ARMv8.4
  3. 32 bits: ARMv6, ARMv5, ARMv4T, ARMv3, ARMv2
- [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC)
- [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontrollers)
- [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture)

Y la lista continúa.

Además, debes seleccionar el sistema operativo donde tendrás que ejecutar la aplicación, que si ya es complicado el tema seleccionando hardware, imagínate seleccionando también un SO.

Una vez lo seleccionas todo, ya puedes ver si el desarrollador ha realizado esa versión específicamente para esa plataforma hardware y software, simultáneamente. Si sí, perfecto. Y si no, pues te aguantas o lo compilas tú.

---

> Bueno el tema es que el 99% de todas las Apps en Snapcraft están compiladas solo para arquitecturas "amd64" que tengo entendido que funciona para cualquier procesador Intel o AMD de 64 bits y no para ARM así sea de 64 bits, aunque la Raspberry Pi 3 B+ en Ubuntu Core se instala como de 32 bits.

Si no nos defines qué es Snapcraft, te cerrarán la pregunta por ser basada en opiniones, porque nadie te dice que sea lo mejor o lo peor según el criterio de cada uno. La idea es que tú nos especifiques cosas específicas, SO (stack overflow) no es un sitio para este tipo de preguntas.

Indiferentemente de que te inventes el porcentaje, tú te respondes y tú te confundes solo. Si un programa (App) está compilado para un procesador Intel o AMD, no está compilado para un procesador ARM, porque, como has visto en la sección anterior, no son procesadores similares. El resultado es que, a menos que tengas el código fuente, no podrás tener jamás ese programa ejecutando en tu Raspberry PI a menos que realices una emulación X86 en tu Raspberry PI.

---

Un ejemplo (que no quiere decir que sea exactamente lo que tienes que hacer), aparece en https://eltechs.com/run-spotify-on-raspberry-pi/:

Aviso: está en inglés

## Spotify installation instruction

### Configure Raspbian

1. For smooth running of Spotify we recommend to increase swap space. Open configuration file in Terminal (command line) using the following command:

   `$ sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile`

Raspbian has 100MB of swap by default. You should change it to 2000MB in the configuration file. So you will have to find this line:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=100
```

And then change it into:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048
```

Press F3 key to save changes and F2 to close the file. Then restart dphys-swapfile to apply changes:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```

### Install ExaGear Desktop

2. Download ExaGear Desktop archive with installation packages and license key. Open Terminal (command line) and unpack the downloaded archive using the following command:

   `$ tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi3.tar.gz`
3. Install and activate ExaGear by running install-exagear.sh script:

   `$ sudo ./install-exagear.sh`

### Launch guest x86 system

4. Enter the guest x86 system by using the following command:

   `$ exagear`

Starting the shell in the guest image /opt/exagear/images/debian-8
 5. Now you are in the x86 environment that can be checked by running the ‘arch’ command:

```
$ arch
```

> i686

6. It is recommended to update apt-get repositories on the first launch of the guest system:

   `$ sudo apt-get update`

### Install Spotify

7. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify the downloaded packages:

   `$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886`
8. Add the Spotify repository:

   `$ echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`
9. Update list of available packages:

   `$ sudo apt-get update`
10. Install Spotify:

Install Spotify

```
$ sudo apt-get install spotify-client
$ sudo apt-get install libxss1
```

---

> El caso es que por ejemplo, si queremos usar una Raspberry Pi también con una impresora que solo cuenta con los drivers para "amd64" no va funcionar

Ni va a funcionar, ni funcionará, a menos que tú recompiles los drivers para esa impresora.

> porque el equipo de Raspberry PI no utiliza un sistema compatible con amd64

Lo que quieres y lo que necesitas son cosas diferentes. No es que no se pretenda utilizar otro procesador distinto para que te encuentres con esta problemática a propósito, es que un procesador AMD64 (sólo procesador) para sistemas embebidos consume varias veces más que toda la placa de una Raspberry Pi al completo.

Otra de las causas de la fama de Raspberry Pi no fue el equipo, sino la comunidad que hay detrás. Ellos son los responsables que se extienda la palabra de boca en boca.

---

Ahora, si tras este gran texto, te cierran la pregunta y me borran el mensaje, lo entenderé perfectamente, porque esto que he hecho no es el objetivo de Stack Overflow en Español.

Answer (score 0):

@AndreOlaya, tal como te explica @Trauma, la pregunta es muy abierta, pero eso no implica que sea mala pregunta (aunque para los términos de SO, lo es y lo más probable es que termine cerrada).

Me parece que tu background es más software que hardware, así que la pregunta es válida e intentaré darte una idea de qué pasa.

Los procesadores (Hardware) están creados de diferente forma, tienen diferentes componentes y por ende, las instrucciones para controlarlos son diferentes, esto está relacionado con la arquitectura. Tienes por ejemplo, los x86 y amd64 (de 32 bits y 64 bits respectivamanete), muy usados en PC y Laptops. Tienes además la arquitectura ARM, propagada en smartphones y otros dispositivos (como el RaspberryPi). Hay más arquitecturas como  MSP430, AVR, PIC encontradas en el ámbito de microcontroladores, algunas de 8 y 16 bits.

Al compilar una aplicacion de alto nivel, lo que haces es generar código para una arquitectura específica, así que una aplicacion compilada para amd64 no se puede ejecutar en una plataforma ARM, *el hardware no lo soporta*.

Una tercera solución, adicional a cambiar hardware o software, es conseguir el codigo fuente del software requerido y **compilarlo** para tu plataforma/arquitectura.

Espero que haya podido aclarar un poco tu duda.